# How do I restore Thunderbird email under Linux?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have both a .thunderbird and a .mozilla-thunderbird from an existing installation.

I installed Thunderbird 3.0b3 under Fedora 11, but it doesn't seem to see the email in either of those directories.

How can I restore my old settings and email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply drop them into your home directory.

example:

```
cp -r /media/USBStick/backup/.thunderbird ~
cp -r /media/USBStick/backup/.mozilla-thunderbird ~
```

make sure your applications also have sufficient read permissions to these files.

Comment: That's what I thought, but for some reason it's not working.  Permissions are OK, and it's finding one account, but none of the other accounts or sub-folders.

Comment: try reconfiguring thunderbird with apt

Answer (score 2):

I always used `cp --archive SOURCE TARGET/` to duplicate folder trees. The **--archive** option does everything as `--recursive --no-dereference --preserve=all`. Where **--preserve=all** includes mode, ownership, timestamps, context, links, and xattr.

There are too many soft links and ownership and permission details that a straight `cp -r` does not accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as Saint DanBert, but I usually use tar.

1. tar -cvzf thunder.tar.gz .mozilla-thunderbird/ .mozilla/
2. move it to the new computer
3. tar -xvzf thunder.tar.gz